# Creating a selectable text content in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I need to create a report page my WPF project, the content for which has be generated dynamically. So I need to bind the content from the view model. This is what I implemented:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Padding="5">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyListCategoryWise}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Key}" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                                <ColumnDefinition />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=ItemDescription}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" IsReadOnly="True" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCountString, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

So this is creating a form with required text in proper format I want, but the problem is it is not having select content support. (select all , copy etc)

So I am looking for putting this whole content in a single multi line textbox probably (which would have all that select, copy etc support). Generating a string in viewmodel from this List which i bound here. But then again I can't show the formatted text in that case (like some of content I could show bold)

What could be the best control to show this kind of a report in WPF.

Comment: When you say 'this content is not selectable', can you describe the kind of selection you'd like the user to make? Are you looking for something that can be click-dragged over in a single movement for copy/pasting, or something that can be selected with a single click, or something that allows multi-selection with multiple clicks, or something completely different?

Comment: I am looking for similar behaviour like we have on this website page content. I should be able to do following:
- Select all by Ctrl+A
- Clicking mouse left button and dragging down to select content
- double click and select any word or again double clicking to select whole report content (i. e . a select all)

Comment: And what format is your content in?

Comment: I just want to make few line bold (sort of paragraph) and for these lines where would be some child content (multiple lines) which I want to show after one tab space. Check the xaml, this xaml creates exact content I am looking for, but need selection feature

Comment: Just use a TextBox rather than a TextBlock

Comment: Which one of the three TextBlocks would you replace with a TextBox, and how would that help with the problem described?

Comment: Yea, I tried with a multiline textbox ( by setting min lines and max lines), but how can make some content bold? Because after all I will have to bind a single string (will have to generate a single string from my collection in the view model side in this case)!

Comment: Any you want to select.  A TextBox is selectable and a TextBlock is not.

Comment: That doesn't address the problem - you can't drag over three TextBoxes and select all of their content at the same time.

Comment: It address the stated question.  "But the problem with this is that this content is not selectable."   The answer can only be as good as the problem statement.

Comment: i Guess Blam meant that I should use just a single textbox and should show the whole content in that. And I tried exactly that, but in this case I can't do the formatting of text !

Comment: Blam I had mentioned it in the question also, in the second last line. I don't know why you marked my question down :-(

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the best control to show this kind of a report in WPF.

Have you considered DocumentViewer and writing your report to a file. 
Another good way to create a report would be something like crystal reports. It has a report creator to help make the report, and you can do all the things you want to do once it's generated in the crystal viewer.

I would say those are the best ways to show (simplest) a report in WPF.

Comment: will I have to create a document (like pdf, ms word etc) first in the view model and then bind that document to the document viewer ?

Comment: Well you would have to create the document, but you could have it just open up in the document viewer when you hit a button, or create it when you hit a button and show up by itself directly after. You're creating a computer program, the sky is the limit =)